# disabling apache logging to access.log

Tags: linux, apache, logging

I've been reading about disabling the logging of the apache server, which is crucial for me as I'm running huge tests on it, and it fills the disk.

I've tried changing http.conf and directing stuff to /dev/null, but none of it worked, as most of it was the Error logging.

Any idea anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 43):

Just comment the areas where logging was set.

On,

```
httpd.conf
virtual hosts configurations (virtual.conf, domain.conf etc)
```

For something like

```
CustomLog logs/access_log common
ErrorLog logs/error_log
```

Just do,

```
#CustomLog logs/access_log common
#ErrorLog logs/error_log
```

Comment: My conf file is apache2.conf and it doesnt have anything like that :(
My httpd.conf file is empty

Comment: Do a find on all the configuration files. grep -r "ErrorLog" /path/to/apache/config

Comment: Sweet, I didn't get the acceptance.. :(

Comment: Because of your changes, if you're not able to start apache after commenting out said lines, then you can do try following:
Just change actual target directory to null device:
   `ErrorLog /dev/null`

Comment: Uncommenting doesn't disable anything, just sets back to default. /dev/null seems like a better answer.

Comment: To find the line try `grep -ri errorlog /etc/{httpd,apache,apache2}`

Comment: Setting to `/dev/null` doesn't work on Windows.