# PHP and Apache - how do I stop the system from writing to the access log?

Tags: php, apache, access-log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disabling apache logging to access.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552312/disabling-apache-logging-to-access-log)

I think the access log by itself takes a lot of system resources because of all the disk access.  How can I prevent any access log data from being written to the access_log file in my PHP/Apache setup?

Thank you!

Comment: it doesn't take significant resources, and its usefulness far outweighs what it uses

Comment: `apache\conf\httpd.conf` on my windows

Comment: You "think"?  Unless you're running a very high traffic site, Apache's logging is not going to contribute significantly to system resource utilization.  There are a variety of tools out there that can get you from "I think" to "I know" if you are actually experiencing issues.

Comment: @larsks my issue is that i am going from a $5/month server and my application is actually outgrowing it.  So I am trying to squeeze resources out of the current hosting before I figure out how to scale this thing ...which I have no idea how to do :)

Comment: your unlikely to even have the option on such a server, get a VPS

Comment: @Dagon Sorry for my being naive, but a VPS is essentially virtual hosting such as in Amazon, right?

Comment: I have been reading about issues that come up when an application begins to need more than one server. Is that a non-issue with cloud hosting such as Amazon web services?