# CakePHP 2.4.5 access.log gets infinitely larger?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I must be missing something simple, I am running CakePHP 2.4.5 and my access.log file is now over 1GB - it seems to be getting perpetually larger. I didn't set anything special with regard to logging, but I can't seem to figure out where to disable the access log. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Yeah it's an nginx setting - no wonder I couldn't find it in CakePHP settings anywhere. My apologies, new to nginx.

Comment: It's not CakePHP's log, it's Apache's log.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disabling apache logging to access.log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552312/disabling-apache-logging-to-access-log)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure logrotate to rotate you logs (every day/week/month)